# Magnet and electromagnetic wave, and speed of light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, speed-of-light

I have this practice exam question:

> T or F. If you hold a magnet in your hand and wave it back and forth, you will create an electromagnetic wave that moves away from your hand at the speed of light.

Why is the answer true?

Comment: Just a musing, but the "moves away from your hand at the speed of light" phrase is curious, because all electromagnetic waves move at the speed of light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the "back and forth" that you should home in on.

You do not say what sort of "level" you want the answer at, but Faraday's law tells you that a changing magnetic field (as you wave the magnet, the B-field changes at a point in pace) begets some sort of electric field.

If the rate of change of magnetic field is not constant - i.e. there is a second derivative with respect to time (that's where the back and forth comes in), then the electric field that is created will also be time dependent and in turn will generate a time-dependent magnetic field by acting as the "source" (of displacement current) in Ampere's law. This leads to a changing electric field - and so on...

A formal solution to the problem you pose would be quite tricky, but a characteristic of those solutions is that the electric and magnetic fields a distance $r$ from your hand respond to changes in the source that occurred at time $r/c$ previously. That is, the changes in electric and magnetic field propagate outwards at the speed of light.